# journalctl list until last unit start

Tags: systemd, journalctl

A common task one wishes to do, when debugging a service that fails to load, is to look at all log from the last time the service was started.

For example, given

```
Jul 25 08:18:20 raspberrypi ngrok[3105]: Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -log
Jul 25 08:20:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ngrok@ssh.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 25 08:20:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Share local port(s) with ngrok...
Jul 25 08:20:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Share local port(s) with ngrok...
Jul 25 08:20:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Share local port(s) with ngrok.
Jul 25 08:20:04 raspberrypi ngrok[5474]: t=2016-07-25T08:20:04+0000 lvl=warn msg="failed to get home directory, using $HOME instead" err="user: Current not implemented on linux/arm" $HOME=
Jul 25 08:20:04 raspberrypi ngrok[5474]: Failed to open log file '/dev/stdout': open /dev/stdout: no such device or address
```

I want to see all lines since `Jul 25 08:20:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Share local port...`.

Something like `journalctl --boot`, but from the last time service was started.

Is that possible?

Likewise, something like `--list-boots` that lists all the times systemctl has started or stopped the service would allow me to mimic `journalctl --last-start -u svc` behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported.  See https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1942

GitHub user [towolf](https://github.com/towolf) [posted a script](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1942#issuecomment-275111192) in that issue which gets pretty close:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@" || :

# Timestamp when unit transitioned from inactive to active
since=$(systemctl show -p InactiveExitTimestamp "$1" | cut -f 2 -d '=' | cut -f 2-3 -d' ')
# or one minute if unset
since=${since:-1 min ago}

# Get prefix string that this units logs with: most robust
# https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2913#issuecomment-219702148
id=$(systemctl show -p SyslogIdentifier "$1" | cut -f 2 -d '=')

# Get all raw output from unit since start, only from stdout&stderr
# Considering that backend only logs "bad" stack traces to stderr, this should
# always be relevant
service_trace=$(journalctl -o cat --since "$since" -t "$id")
```

Comment: I'm afraid you were wrong - see my answer using systemd 232 (published in November 2016).

Answer (score 1):

Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506833/show-journal-logs-from-the-time-a-service-was-restarted), since systemd 232 you can use systemd's [`INVOCATION_ID`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#%24INVOCATION_ID), which is an ID for the specific *run* of a service. This is what I use :

```bash
function last_log() {
    if [ $# == 1 ] then
        echo -e "\nSyntax: $0 SERVICE_NAME"
        exit 1
    fi
    ID=$(systemctl show -p InvocationID --value $1)
    journalctl INVOCATION_ID=$ID + _SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID=$ID
}
```

Note that providing an invalid service name would lead to inconsistent behaviour, and you loose the benefit of command-line completion.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way of getting the log from the last start of the service is not journalctl but systemctl status: eg

```
sudo systemctl status --no-pager -l -n 99999 svc
```

You can also give a starting time for journalctl, eg 1 hour back:

```
sudo journalctl --no-pager --since='-1h' -u svc
```

or from a specific time: `--since='16:00'`.

Comment: Yes, one can do the very same thing with boot, but it's not as convenient as `-b`